# How can i use $_GET to extract from index.php?23456

Tags: php, html, forms, post, get

How can i use **$_GET** to extract from index.php?23456

For Example :

www.example.com/index.php?**23456**

www.example.com/?**23456**

Or:

www.example.com/index.php?**23456**&**55555**

result should be :

```
echo $string; // result 23456
echo $string2; // result 23456
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this, which is why I'm not posting it as an answer, but you may be able to use something like `$_GET[0]`. Edit: Sorry - comment above answers it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]`](http://php.net/manual/en//reserved.variables.server.php) for the raw, unparsed query string.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel No, this is not true. Can you tell me what is your problem.

Comment: @faressoft yeah. On a side note, this is not a good approach to build URLs IMO. A simple switch of the order of the arguments - usually perfectly possible in a query string - will destroy the URL. I would rather used named arguments (`arg1=123456&arg2=....`) or mod_rewrite to simulate a directory structure

Answer (score 7):

```
$strings = explode("&",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
echo $strings[0];
echo $strings[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` solution, you can consider using names for the params, because if you don't, you can't easily remove or add different params later on.

For example if it is `foo.php?123&456`, then what if later, you decide to just pass in 456 and skip 123?  Or if you can have up to 5 params and in one case you merely want to pass in the 5th one.  In such cases, if you have the form `foo.php?r=1&id=123`, then it is a lot easier to handle.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of retrieving the query:

```
echo parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_QUERY);
```

Then explode the string if necessary.

Comment: Note `REQUEST_URI` is an Apache extension that won't be present on other servers.